# Can a new session be started after session_destory is called within a script?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I have the following basic logout script which I believe to be functioning strangely:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['customerState'] = array("abbr"=>"TX","full"=>"Texas");
$_SESSION['agent']['url'] = "jmarston4";

$fart = isset($_SESSION['customerState']) ? $_SESSION['customerState'] : array();
$url = isset($_SESSION['agent']['url']) ? $_SESSION['agent']['url'] : '';

$_SESSION = array();

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

echo "Fart1: ";
print_r($fart);

session_destroy();

echo "<br>Fart2: ";
print_r($fart);

session_start();

echo "<br>Fart3: ";
print_r($fart);

$_SESSION['fart'] = $fart;

echo "<br>Fart4: ";
print_r($_SESSION['fart']);

#exit;

header('Location: https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' .$url);
```

This page redirects to the site homepage (index.php) with a referrer URL (mentioned as $url). This works just as it should. For testing sake, here is a screen shot of ALL of the code on index.php:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7P86.jpg

If I allow the `exit;` to process, the following is outputted to screen:

> Fart1: Array ( [abbr] => TX [full] => Texas )
>
> Fart2: Array ( [abbr] => TX [full] => Texas )
>
> Fart3: Array ( [abbr] => TX [full] => Texas )
>
> Fart4: Array ( [abbr] => TX [full] => Texas )

(or visually: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNtra.jpg)

In this script (logout.php), I want to keep a single SESSION variable from the customers session (and not manually unset 100+ others) so I can pass it back to the homepage for internal purposes. To do this, the script does the following:

- Set the SESSION variable 'fart' equal an array
- A local variable is then set equal to the SESSION 'fart' before the entire SESSION is destroyed
- The session data is cleared
- The session cookie is deleted
- the session is destroyed
- The SESSION 'fart' is created and set back to the $fart array
- the page redirects to the homepage.

## QUESTION

By design, are PHP SESSIONS expected to behave this way? If so, how can one essentially destory a session (say for logout purposes) while maintaining pieces of session information collected during that user session.

Note: I am using SESSION arrays so passing in the URL for GET purposes is not applicable here.

### Update Notes:

- I changed the title of this question from "Are PHP sessions behaving according to spec?"
- All of this works on the script itself, however, when I try and access $_SESSION['fart'] on the homepage, it is not set. I am able to set, manipulate or alter SESSION variables on the page at any point, INCLUDING after `session_destroy()` is called. For example, if I want to do the following:

  ...
  session_destroy()

  $_SESSION['eatmyshorts'] = "hello!";

  echo $_SESSION['eatmyshorts']; // will display hello!
  ....

  however, once the script (page) ends, anything relating to sessions (even `$_SESSION['eatmyshorts']` in this case, is not available on any other page and disregarded.

Comment: You destroy the session and then set it after. Add another `session_start()` and it should work.

Comment: is  `session_start();` on the home page

Comment: @Horen - tried that. No dice

Comment: @Dagon - yes it is. Nothing on the homepage is missing, as sessions behave as expected coming from all other pages.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You destroy the session data and wonder why there's no session data on subsequent request?

Comment: `session_destroy();` <- take the destroy for real. manipulating the superglobal `$_SESSION` afterwards does not bring a new session back to live. Also keep in mind that setting the session cookie is for *that* request. You can set the same cookie in a request multiple times, however the outcome is the last setting.

Comment: @lafor - I am well aware I destroy the session as it exists on that part of the script. I am then trying to recreate the session and set a specific variable. My question is stated below the bullet points for reference (or in the title of this 'question')

Comment: If you're seriously, then you're doing it wrong. In-real world scenario, a `session` should wrapped into a class, that abstracts implementation details. Then you should inject an instance of `$session` into the classes that need it. Benefits? Adheres to the `SRP` and `DI` and 100% you'll never face problems like this one. Again, the problem is: **this is because you didn't abstract it**

Comment: @Dave - this is a realworld scenario. You do not have to wrap `sessions` in classes for them to function or work in any way whatsoever. I can agree with other parts of your statement but regardless, you do not have to use abstract classes in this case for it function as I believe it should.

Comment: How do you pass the session ID, via cookie only?

Comment: @JM4 You partially missed a point. `Abstract functionality !== Wrap into abstract class`. To abstract this concept means, something like this: `$session = new SessionHandler($cookieParams)` <-- This would ensure that session is started, and you can use it later just like, `$session->read('foo'), $session->write(array('foo' => 'bar'))`. Again, the point here is to : **Decouple session logic from its business one**. Say, if you have `Authorization` class, you would simply inject an instance into its `__construct` ... <- to manage session user storage details.

Comment: @Dave - I admit i am actually trying to solve a real problem, however, at its core, my question is truly above the validity of the way I am realizing PHP sessions are handled when destroy is called and looking for "expert validation" it is such. I will record a brief screen cast to show the issues I am explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `session_destroy`, the [stored session data is destroyed, `$_SESSION` is emptied, and the ‘session state’ is reset as before `session_start` was called](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/session/session.c#122). In that state, the data in `$_SESSION` exists just during runtime. Now if you call `session_start` after `session_destroy`, the session handling behaves exactly as if it where the first active session within the runtime: If the client request contains a syntactically valid session ID, it will use it for this session.

This all *does* work as expected.

However, what you haven’t taken into account is how sessions behave when you delete the session’s cookie containing the ID. Because when you sent the cookie to revoke the session ID for the client, the client won’t send a session ID along the next request and `session_id` will generate a new one. Since it’s a new session, `$_SESSION` is empty.

If you want to revoke the current session ID and generate a new session ID, use [`session_regenerate_id(true)`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id) and [`session_unset`](http://php.net/session_unset).

Comment: great answer - I provided updated question data but not sure it was needed. Your answer makes perfect sense. I have tested and verified this was in fact the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `session_destroy` the session is, well, destroyed and the server-side storage of the session data deleted. Manipulating the `$_SESSION` viariable after that has no effect as it's not "bound" to an actual session anymore (ie. the data you set don't get written to the session data storage when the script ends).

Comment: Fair enough - but for clarification, you are stating that once `session_destroy` is called on a page, there is no way to create a new SESSION on that page.

Comment: @JM4 Why would you want to do that? If you want to delete some session data and keep others, just delete that data instead of destroying the entire session.

Comment: a number of reasons that are to long to type but let's just say for simplicity sake, I want to keep 1 variable and not manually unset 500 others.

Comment: @JM4 Then use `$_SESSION = array('my_one_variable'=>'foo');` optionally followed by `session_write_close();`. Voila, your session now only has one variable.

Comment: based on your logic, if simply resetting the variable of $_SESSION was a valid way to handle logout purposes, then what would be the difference in: `session_unset` `session_destroy` or simply `$_SESSION = array()`

Comment: @JM4 No difference at all; in both cases you "forget" the user's authentity effectively logging him off. Whether you additionally destroy the session or not depends on whether you still need it or not.

Answer (score 0):

> ALL of this works on the script itself
>   Then there is nothing wrong with the code you have provided (apart from the missing session_start(), but you said you put this in - you should edit your code above as people are replying based on it being an obvious error)
>   I tried your code above and confirm it works as stand alone.

To get help, you should explain or (ideally) show the rest of your code so it can be evaluated and the root cause of the issue discovered.

Try changing your bottom bit of code to this and tell us the outcome

```
echo "Fart1: ".$fart;

session_destroy();

echo "<br>Fart2: ".$fart;

session_start();

echo "<br>Fart3: ".$fart;

$_SESSION['fart'] = $fart;
//header('Location: /'); exit; <-- commented out

echo "<br>session: ".$_SESSION['fart'];
```

Although you had it working yourself, and are SURE that `session_start()` is present on the file which it redirects to and is at the top of the file BEFORE any HTML output, also try redirecting to the actual page name just to rule something else out, ie

```
header('Location: index.php'); exit; //or whatever filename is your homepage
```

Also to answer your other question about how to do this properly, how you do it is fine, as you set a var to the value, start the session again and set the $_SESSION to the var value.
You can access $_SESSION data directly, eg

```
$_SESSION['userlogin']['username'] = 'james';
//log me out from the session =
$_SESSION['userlogin']['username'] = '';
```

Comment: there is no 'rest of the code' this is an entire script on logout.php. I use the example of `$_SESSION['fart']` but just assume the actual data contained in it is an array.

Comment: By that I meant the page it redirects to, as if the above works, then the issue is elsewhere. Run my echo code above to make sure everything is in place (ie mainly the session still has the data just before redirect) then we can assume the issue is not on this script (ie perhaps the homepage has the issue somewhere)

Comment: as requested, I have gone ahead and tested the code you mention and as I referred to, anything I do on that script itself behaves as expected: http://screencast.com/t/eT0XYXVlO

it is only on the redirect issues occur

Comment: in which case the issue is on the homepage - at the very top of the page, right after `session_start()` do this - `echo "Homepagesession: ".$_SESSION['fart'];`

Comment: As mentioned, I have already done this: `Notice: Undefined index: fart in (path)\index.php on line 4`

Comment: It's just a  notice, so I presume the code works then? Can we see your first 10 lines from index.php?

Comment: How do you assume "it works". If the index is not defined it means the session variable was *not* carried over to the index.php page. Just assume it is as listed in the updated question because the rest of the page does not affect it.

Comment: I do not know without seeing the code, which is why I keep asking for it :) (I presumed it works as it's only a notice). So, can we see the first 10 lines of the code? What did my last request output on index.php - `echo "Homepagesession: ".$_SESSION['fart'];` did the script halt? Did it echo or not echo anything? Just the error, or is the error from the log file and not on the page? Need info :)

Comment: It is irrelevant what the rest of the script is. Assume index.php is just the following:

`<?php session_start(); print_r($_SESSION['fart']); exit;`

Comment: ok (I'll assume that is what it actually is accurately, and not just typed here ;)) what was the outcome from using a direct file redirect, rather than just forward slash? ie `header('Location: index.php'); exit;`